# How to disable the reported weak KEX algorithm(s) on centOS7?

Tags: security, centos7

I'm newbie on linux centos7(7.8.2003). I have vulnerability scan and found detection "Weak Key Exchange (KEX) Algorithm(s) Supported (SSH)". The recommned solution need to disable the reported weak KEX algorithm(s). I try to solve by follow the link https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-disable-weak-cipher-and-insecure-hmac-algorithms-in-ssh-services-for-centos-rhel-6-and-7/

```
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

But scan result still the same. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: In SSH 'kex' (key-exchange) algorithms and cipher algorithms are completely separate, unrelated, and not connected, and setting one has nothing to do with the other. But this is not about programming or development and out of scope for SO; see https://serverfault.com/questions/1083015/how-do-i-disable-sshd-algorithms instead, but first identify _which_ algorithms you want to remove, or alternatively which ones you want to keep.